# How to compare months in a DRY way?

Tags: javascript

I'm building a WordPress based application and the client will have an option to choose data entered over the last year in quarters. I would love to make this code much smarter but I'm not sure how to do it. The data looks something like this in JS:

```
idsh: Array[4]
    0: "565"
    1: "565"
    2: "567"
    3: "569"
    length: 4
datesh: Array[4]
    0: "12/22/2014 - 00:00:00, 12:00 AM"
    1: "01/21/2015 - 00:00:00, 12:00 AM"
    2: "01/28/2015 - 00:00:00, 12:00 AM"
    3: "02/04/2015 - 00:00:00, 12:00 AM"
    length: 4
ids: Array[5]
    0: "1009"
    1: "979"
    2: "1009"
    3: "1011"
    4: "1013"
    length: 5
dates: Array[5]
    0: "01/05/2015 - 00:00:00, 12:00 AM"
    1: "12/22/2014 - 00:00:00, 12:00 AM"
    2: "02/13/2015 - 00:00:00, 12:00 AM"
    3: "02/20/2015 - 00:00:00, 12:00 AM"
    4: "02/27/2015 - 00:00:00, 12:00 AM"
    length: 5
```

```js
    var getQuarters = (function() {
      'use strict';
      var dates = [
        "01/05/2015 - 00:00:00, 12:00 AM",
        "12/22/2014 - 00:00:00, 12:00 AM",
        "02/13/2015 - 00:00:00, 12:00 AM",
        "02/20/2015 - 00:00:00, 12:00 AM",
        "02/27/2015 - 00:00:00, 12:00 AM"
      ];

      function loops(items, fn, onLoopComplete) {
        var i;
        try {
          if (items && items.length) {
            i = items.length;
          } else {
            throw new Error(items + ' is required to have a length');
          }

          if (i > -1) {
            do {
              if (items[i] !== undefined) {
                fn(i);
                /* console.log(i + ' is the current iteration'); */
              }
            }
            while (--i >= 0);
          }
          if (typeof onLoopComplete === 'function') {
            onLoopComplete(items.length);
          }
        } catch (e) {
          throw new Error(e);
        }
      }


      function show3() {
        loops(dates, function(i) {
          var months = dates[i].slice(0, 2),
            thisMonth = new Date().getMonth();

          if (months == thisMonth ||
            months == thisMonth - 1 ||
            months == thisMonth - 2) {
            console.log(months);
          } else {
            console.log(dates[i] + ' do not meet criteria.');
          }
        });
      }

      function show6() {
        loops(dates, function(i) {
          var months = dates[i].slice(0, 2),
            thisMonth = new Date().getMonth();

          if (months == thisMonth ||
            months == thisMonth - 1 ||
            months == thisMonth - 2 ||
            months == thisMonth - 3 ||
            months == thisMonth - 4 ||
            months == thisMonth - 5) {
            console.log(months);
          } else {
            console.log(dates[i] + ' do not meet criteria.');
          }
        });
      }


      return function(quarters) {
        switch (quarters) {
          case 2:
            show6();
            break;
          case 3:
            show9();
            break;
          case 4:
            show12();
            break;
          default:
            show3();
            break;
        }
      };
    }());

    getQuarters();
```

I loop through the dates available to see if they match a criteria, (like the last 3 months) but [my code](http://jsbin.com/wuzegu/32/edit?js,console) is very repetitive right now. How do I make it smarter and DRY?

Comment: 1. How about you *show* us some code? 2. You want *dry* code? As in "don't do anything, just print what you would do"?

Comment: I recommend you to use moment.js it helps a lot to reduce code.

Comment: @Siguza please see the jsbin for code. - In case you missed it: http://jsbin.com/wuzegu/32/edit?js,console

Comment: @colecmc Yeah, I missed that, sorry. Leaving only a link is considered bad practise though, because the link might die and your question would have no value to future readers. It would be very kind of you to take the time to inline the relevant bits.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
function showLastMonths(numberOfMonths){
  loops(dates, function(i) {
     var months = dates[i].slice(0, 2),
     thisMonth = new Date().getMonth();

     monthDifferential = thisMonth - months
     if (monthDifferential > 0 && monthDifferential <= numberOfMonths ) {
        console.log(months);
        console.log(ids[i]);
     } else {
        console.log(dates[i] + ' do not meet criteria.');
     }
    });
}
```

This is the easiest refactoring that i can see there, just extract a parameter and delete the show3 show6 etc functions and call that instead.